# How can I visualize Primal-Dual Hill climbing?

Tags: algorithm

In the text, How to Think About Algorithms by Jeff Edmonds, there's a section explaining Primal-Dual Hill Climbing in the Network Flows and Linear Programming chapter. I'm having trouble visualizing the exponential number of roofs and why the 'lowest and hence optimal roof is above the highest and hence optimal place to stand'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this is right but this was my take: given a particular hilly topology that you're navigating, imagine its mirror image floating in the sky above you. The top of the tallest hill will reach up and come into contact with the bottom of the bottom most valley of the mirror, which is reaching down from the sky. Conversely, if you navigate down into the lowest valley you'll maximize the distance between you and the point directly above you in the mirror image. It's not explained very well in the book but this mirror image is the "exponential roofs" referred to in the book.

Anyways, this mirror image is used as the basis for the proof that you've reached a global maximum. Intuitively what the proof is saying is that, first of all, the mirror image is another instance of the original problem, just reversed. However, the presence of the mirror image above you in the sky is what allows you to distinguish between a local or global maximum. If you've reached a particular peak but your head isn't bumping up against its "mirror peak" in the sky then you've reached a local maximum. If, on the other hand, there's no room for you to stand because the peak is bumped up against its mirror image then you know you've reached a global maximum.

Going back to the original description in the book, I think its problematic because what the author describes as "exponential roofs" sounded to me like a series of hills with a bunch of gazebos on it, and that's not right. A better description would be a cave of stalagmites and stalactites that exactly mirror each other.